# NoSuchMethodError - When I call javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity

Tags: java, tomcat, cxf, tomcat8, nosuchmethoderror

I'm encountering an issue in a Java project where I'm receiving the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity

This error occurs when I call javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity. It appears that the error is happening within an interceptor.

The exception:

> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity

I'm using Tomcat 8.5.83 with JDK 1.8. The project is utilizing JAX-RS (Java API for RESTful Web Services) along with Apache CXF to implement a RESTful service client.

I have verified that all the necessary dependencies are included in my project, and I haven't come across any obvious compatibility issues.

Despite these checks, I'm still unsure why I'm getting this error. Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any ideas on how to resolve it? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The log for more details:

```
2023-05-19 11:32:26.254 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] WARN  o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain line: 449 - Application ***** has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:189) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:298) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:222) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:656) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:273) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:885) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1693) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.83]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_362-362]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at it.paybay.payment.service.*****.*****(*****.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
    at it.paybay.payment.rest.*****.*****(*****.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_362-362]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_362-362]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_362-362]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_362-362]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
2023-05-19 11:32:26.258 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] WARN  o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain line: 493 - Exception in handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSDefaultFaultOutInterceptor@c143a8f
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:189) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:298) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:222) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:656) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:273) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:885) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1693) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.83]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_362-362]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at it.paybay.payment.service.*****.*****(*****.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
    at it.paybay.payment.rest.*****.*****(*****.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_362-362]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_362-362]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_362-362]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_362-362]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
2023-05-19 11:32:26.260 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] ERROR o.a.c.i.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver line: 114 - Error occurred during error handling, give up!
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:189) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:298) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:222) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:656) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:273) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:885) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1693) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.83]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_362-362]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at it.paybay.payment.service.*****.*****(*****.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
    at it.paybay.payment.rest.*****.*****(*****.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_362-362]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_362-362]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_362-362]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_362-362]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

**Edit 1:**

Image with the dependency's version and where the error occurs:
[image: Code]

Comment: That method was added in JAX-RS 2.0. It seems like the spec version you're using is some 1.x version. Can you add your JAX-RS dependencies?

Comment: @RobSpoor I added an image that might help.

Comment: you didn't. Rob asked for the dependency versions. The error points to the fact he describes: You've got the api jar and a different version for the impl.